# how to convert an image to array for feeding into a model using numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, deep-learning, h5py

I have downloaded this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datamunge/sign-language-mnist) form kaggle. I have trained a model based on this dataset. Now the question is if I upload an image for prediction, how should I convert that image into a NumPy array. In the case of this dataset, there were labels like pixel1,pixel2,pixel3 .... pixel 784, label in the CSV file.Also if anybody can help me do I need to convert images into GRAY scale

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```